# MySQL merging two queries one with group by

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one holds user info (id, name, etc) and another table that holds user tickets and ticket status (ticket_id, user_id, ticket_status, etc).

I want to produce a list of ALL the users for example: `( SELECT * FROM user_table )`

And for each user I need a count of their tickets for example: 
`(SELECT t1.user_id, COUNT(*) FROM user_tickets t1 WHERE t1.ticket_status = 15 GROUP BY t1.ticket_status, t1.user_id )`

I can do this query to achieve what I’m looking for but it takes 5sec. to run the query on 50000 tickets, while each query running separately only takes fraction of a second.

```
SELECT t1.user_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM user_tickets t1 
LEFT JOIN user_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.group_id = 20 AND t1.status_id = 15 
GROUP BY t1.status_id, user_id
```

Any idea how to write the query to get same performance as each separately?

Comment: indexes on all the fields in the where and join clauses is the usual first step.

Comment: Also try adding EXPLAIN in front of your query to find out what mysql is doing - posting the results from the explain are usefull as well

Comment: side note: `t2.group_id = 20` should be in the ON clause of your left join

Comment: @Sebas Do you think that would make a difference? Hoping the mysql optimizer would work that out itself

Comment: @MarcB A thought - also a single index with fields in the correct order could help. But I knew you also meant that ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish, putting in in the where clause changes the left join into an inner join, that's why it should be corrected.

Comment: @Sebas Thanks for teaching me that - makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

An indexing where clause fixed the problem.